# MySQL aunthentication fails on php but not in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, phpmyadmin

I am developing a PHP website with MySQL access. My hosting site is shared and I created a DB from the `phpmyadmin` that is installed on the shared hosting server. I created 2 users, one with administrative privileges, the other having only read/write privileges. I can connect with phpmyadmin using both accounts successfully but when I tried to access mysql using the same accounts and using the same credentials, php gives me a:

```
Database connection failed: Access denied for user 'myusername'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Which is very weird. `PHPMyAdmin` says that the server is localhost so that means I am using the correct server parameter to my `mysql_connect` function in php.

Does anyone have any idea what went wrong? Could it be possible that mysql is only enabled for PHPMyAdmin (which is absurd)?

Thank you very much and I'll appreciate the help. :)

Here is a sample code (username and password are replaced for security purpose):

```
defined('DB_SERVER') ? null : define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
defined('DB_USER')   ? null : define("DB_USER", "host_admin");
defined('DB_PASS')   ? null : define("DB_PASS", "mysuperpassword");
defined('DB_NAME')   ? null : define("DB_NAME", "mydb_inhostingserver");

...

$this->connection = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS);

if (!$this->connection) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
} else {
    $db_select = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $this->connection);

    if (!$db_select) {
    die("Database selection failed: " . mysql_error());
    }
}
```

...

```
Database connection failed: Access denied for user 'host_admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I also echoed the 4 constants and their values are correct! I'm really lost here...

### Additional Information:

- The FTP address is: ftp.thewebsiteimtalkingabout.com
- The PhpMyAdmin address is: mysql.thewebsiteimtalkingabout.com

So would this mean that they my code and MySQL's phpmnyadmin is running on the same host?

### Answer:

Ok so I was testing the theory that they are in a different server although their domain's are the same. I extracted their respective ipaddress and found that they are different. I then replaced the 'localhost' parameter to the ipaddress of where the phpmyadmin resides then boom! It's now connected. Thank you very much for the replies everyone!

Comment: Could you share a piece of code?

Comment: Are you sure your hosting server phpmyadmin lists the db server as localhost?

Comment: yup! it says localhost at the top and when I login, it displays my username followed by @localhost

Comment: You should check whether your host prefixes your db names and usernames with your account name. With Hostmonster, they prefixed my db names with "gustavbe_".

Comment: Post your answer as an answer to the post

Answer (score 3):

Eepot - that doesnt mean that your application sits on the same server as the mySQL database.

For instance, on my host, the database it on another server - but phpmyadmin is ALSO on THAT server. This means that "phpmyadmin" is reporting the server as "localhost" - but my application needs to connect to the server using the full server name.

You need to ask your hosting provider for the details to connect to your mySQL server.

Comment: I also thought of that, but still asked about it since if the tech support says that the server is indeed localhost, then I have a followup question. Anyways, I am contacting them now and I'll update it if that is the problem.

Comment: That would imply that we also has a localhost mysql, as he is getting a response from mysql - not a host not found or so. Eopot, can you confirm that your running code is on another server than the DB?

Comment: ahh, their technical support is busy and I'll have a return call in a moment. Would it help if I say that both URLs (the phpmyadmin URL) and my FTP url are in the same domain? The urls are in this format: ftp.thedomain.com and mysql.thedomain.com...

Comment: @EepotAdkja Hey Eepot different subdomain may or may not mean they are on different machines. I am not a php guru but what might help you is to right a utility webpage which prints an IP of the machine it's running on. Finally use PHPAdmin to create a user with your app server's IP http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/adding-users.html

Comment: @EepotAdkja damn it! could have been my answer:)

Comment: Thanks eppot - if this was correct then if you could mark it as 'accepted' that would be awesome :)